# Retrieve values from HTML form

Tags: php

I have a mail sending functionality in php code, I want to use define  to set to address and from address.How can this be done.

The code is

```
   <?php

 $subject = 'Test email';

$message = "Hello World!\n\nThis is my first mail.";

$headers = "From: $from\r\nReply-To: webmaster@example.com";
  //send the email
   $mail = @mail( $to, $subject, $message, $headers );

 ?>
```

How to define $to and $from.    Thanks in Advance for help

Comment: Why do you want to use define for the `to` and `from` addresses?

Comment: You're question is somewhat vague. What do you mean by "define"? Do you want people to fill a form and for PHP to retrieve these values?

Comment: to know how that can be done .

Answer (score 0):

Here's a very basic example. I'll leave it up to you to do validation.

HTML:

```
<form action="path/to/your/script.php" method="post">
  <input type="text" name="from" />
  <input type="submit" value="Send" />
</form>
```

PHP:

In PHP, you'll want to use [`$_REQUEST`](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.request.php), [`$_POST`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.post.php) or [`$_GET`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php) depending on the `action` parameter of the `form` in your HTML. If you're not sure, use `$_REQUEST`. The value that goes in the square brackets is the `name` of attribute of the `input` from your HTML.

```
define('TO_ADDRESS', 'user@example.org');

$headers = "From: " . $_REQUEST['from'] . "\r\nReply-To: webmaster@example.com";
$mail = mail(TO_ADDRESS, $subject, $message, $headers);
```

Comment: i also want to know then is there any usage of using DEFINE for any purpose @Francois

Comment: @work - Not in this case. The `define` function is for is for constants (values that don't change). If the user will be inputting the data, it will change and therefore you don't want to use `define`. For more information, see [http://ca.php.net/define](http://ca.php.net/define).

Comment: @work, you use it for constant values e.g. a non-changing value of a `to` address e.g. `define("TO_ADDRESS", "name@email.com");`

Comment: and can we use this as $to in mail() function @tradyblix

Comment: if the `to` address is meant to be constant, like if it's an admin email to where you send emails from people, yes because it's not meant to change e.g. `mail(TO_ADDRESS, $subject, $message, $headers)`

Comment: @Francois Deschenes, you can remove the `@` in `@mail` so he see errors come out if there's a problem ;)

Comment: @tradyblix - Absolutely. I agree. @work - I should have mentioned that it's bad practice to use the @ symbol. You should avoid using it if you can.

Comment: @work - Did you ever get this stuff figured out? I haven't heard back since yesterday and you haven't accepted any answers. Let me know if you still need help.

Answer (score 0):

Unless it is absolutely imperative, I would recommend using a good old fashioned variable for this particular task, not a constant.

If you do want to use a constant:

```
define('MAIL_TO', 'mailto@gmail.com');
define('MAIL_FROM', 'mailfrom@gmail.com');

$subject = 'Test email';
$message = "Hello World!\n\nThis is my first mail.";
$headers = "From: " . MAIL_FROM . "\r\nReply-To: webmaster@example.com";

$mailResult = mail(MAIL_TO, $subject, $message, $headers);
```

FYI:

```
// Constants can also be retrieved with the constant() function
$mailTo = constant('MAIL_TO');

// ...which is the same as...
$mailTo = MAIL_TO;
```

With use of constants:

```
$mailTo   = 'mailto@gmail.com';
$mailFrom = 'mailfrom@gmail.com';
$subject  = 'Test email';
$message  = "Hello World!\n\nThis is my first mail.";
$headers  = "From: " . $mailFrom . "\r\nReply-To: webmaster@example.com";

$mailResult = mail($mailTo, $subject, $message, $headers);
```